# Make in leaflet custom icons with different colors

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I make leaflet@1.6.0 custom icons from docs https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/
and I need to give possiblity for users  set select custom colors for these icons
and I wonder if there is a way to set colors to custom icons?
Like I do for markers :

```
  markers: [{
                id: 1,
                location: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),
                color: '#c11a1a',
                strokeColor: '#d73534',
                circleColor: '#590000',
                content_text: ' <strong>content text</strong> #1',
                opened: true
            },
```

?
If yes, how ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `<input type='color'>` in html page and get the hex color in js using an eventhandler and then use the hexCode in your marker color.

Comment: That is too vague. Could you please give a link to similar snippet ?